# Accordion menu for weebly

Tags: accordion

Hello I am using Weebly Pro and I would like to learn how to make an accordion side bar. Now it will currently open the submenus next to the menu and it makes huge mess.

this is my website:
www.exceptyebeconverted.com

I would like something more like this:
www.excatholicsforchrist.com

I need some extreme help. I have searched google and youtube for help and have not been able to understand any of it enough to help me. That is why I am here. 
How could I edit this code to get the accordion effect? Do I have to change HTML as well? Does that mean I change the page layout?

```
<body class="wsite-theme-light short-header-page">
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        {logo}
        <div id="avmenu">{menu}</div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-wrap">
        <div id="header">
            <table id="header-right">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="phone-number">{phone:text}</td>
                                <td class="social">{social}</td>
                                <td class="search">{search}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="banner">
            <div class="wsite-header"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">{content}</div>
            <div id="footer">{footer}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</body>

/* side-nav
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#avmenu {
    clear: left;
    margin: 70px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#avmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#avmenu li {
    list-style: none;
}

#avmenu li a {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #903f3f;
}

#avmenu ul > li:last-child a,
#avmenu ul > span:last-child li a {
    border-bottom: none;
}

#avmenu li#active a,
#avmenu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #903f3f;
}

/* Navigation Drop-Down Menu Customization
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #903f3f;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
    padding: 8px;
    background: #903f3f;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bd5353;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #723131;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLy3vaIhyKA

Also, since this is using JQuery, there are other JQuery based accordion widgets you can use, like https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ and http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-accordion/

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help

Comment: I see you placed the CSS. Place the HTML as well so we can try to help. You can use https://jsfiddle.net/ to show us what you have.

Comment: Thanks. I added the html at the top of it.

Comment: I see the HTML is built with tables and have words like `{menu}` in it. Are those place holders for the actual menu? Is `{menu}` a keyword to be replaced with a full menu? If so, its HTML is what really interesting, and it's missing.

Comment: I am not sure... does this help?

%%MENU%%
%%MENU%% is a variable that is replaced with the code for your site’s navigation menu.  The menu is generated as an unordered HTML list.  The active link in the menu will have the id “active” that you can style with CSS.  

Here is example output from the %%MENU%% variable:

    <ul>
      <li id="active"><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>

Comment: It does, actually, but you'll still need correct CSS and probably add javascript to make the accordion work. First handle the CSS and make it look like a long list. Then handle the closing and opening of the sub-sections. Is the UL hierarchical?